# In MySQL, how do I write a query to select ranges of data from locations in another table?

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to process a large block of simulation data (~2Gb worth).  The data is in a table which looks like:

```
Table: Simulation Data
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|   id  | run_id | timestep | value |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|     1 |   1    |     1    | 0.00  |
|     2 |   1    |     2    | 0.003 |
|     : |   :    |     :    |   :   |
|  9543 |   1    |  9543    | 0.23  |
|  9544 |   2    |     1    | 0.00  |
|     : |   :    |     :    |   :   |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
```

So for each run (identified by a run_id) there are a number of time steps with corresponding data (in the case of run_id 1, there were 9543 time steps).

Durring a simulation run, there are events which take place.  These event time steps are recorded in another table:

```
Table: Simulation Events
+-------+--------+----------+
|   id  | run_id | timestep |
+-------+--------+----------+
|    1  |   1    |  152     |
|    2  |   1    |  193     |
|    3  |   1    |  382     |
|    :  |   :    |   :      |
|  143  |   1    |  9382    |
|  144  |   2    |  137     |
|    :  |   :    |   :      |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

So for this set of data, with run_id 1, there were events at time step 152, 193, 382, ... 9382.  run_id 2 has its first event at time step 137, etc.  I am interested in what happens in the 3-timesteps before, the time step of, and the 3-timesteps after each event for each run_id.  I would like to put together a query that returns something that looks like:

```
+--------+----------------+----------+-------+
| run_id | event_timestep | delta_ts | value |
+--------+----------------+----------+-------+
|    1   |      152       |   -3     | 0.053 |
|    1   |      152       |   -2     | 0.042 |
|    1   |      152       |   -1     | 0.031 |
|    1   |      152       |    0     | 0.003 |
|    1   |      152       |    1     | 0.532 |
|    1   |      152       |    2     | 0.736 |
|    1   |      152       |    3     | 1.138 |
|    1   |      193       |   -3     | 0.049 |
|    :   |       :        |    :     |   :   |
|    1   |     9382       |   -3     | 0.068 |
|    :   |       :        |    :     |   :   |
|    1   |     9382       |    3     | 1.523 |
+--------+----------------+----------+-------+
```

Where the first row, with delta_ts = -3 would be the value from timestep 149, -2 would be from timestep 150, -1 from timestep 151, etc. Any thoughts on putting together a query that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two differing points of view on this:

- You can use blank joins (cartesian products) `select ... from table t1, table t2 where ...`, but you have to figure out a condition that links two rows *if and only if* they're "related". Also keep in mind that pairs are commutative in your example, so add a condition like `t1.id<t2.id` -- also excludes self-joins.
- or you can use a cursor in a stored procedure, and store values for the previous `n` steps, and correlate them manually. This is slower, uses more memory, but it's easier to write.

Comment: @Blindy- When you mention using a cursor in a stored procedure.  Do you mean something along the lines of selecting the timesteps from the events table where run_id = x, and iterate over those values, selecting the ranges from the simulation data table?  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Once you have your forward cursor, you can run additional queries for each step, or just storing the previous (few) rows in a set of variables (or a temporary table) and aggregate them on the spot. I really think you shouldn't go this route though!

Comment: I agree- it sounds slow.  Though I've been trying to figure out how to do these joins for the first example, and am getting nowhere.  I'll go read up on blank joins and see what I come up with.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Thanks Blindy- I got everything up and running (quite fast) using cartesian products.  You definitely got me moving in the right direction!

Comment: Yay another cursor-free convert! :)